# What can be done to prevent notifications like "Login items added" Mac OSX Ventura Dev Beta 2 22A5286j

Tags: notifications, launchd

Using Mac OSX Ventura Dev Beta 2 Build No: 22A5286j.

Despite the fact that I already uninstalled OpenVPN I'm getting hundreds of notifications when I start my Mac.

Checked LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons folders, deleted openvpn plist files. No sucssess

What can be done?

[image]

Comment: File a Bug Report. It's beta software.

Comment: Hi! Two things would make this more likely to get positive votes and an answer. 1 [list the build you have - beta 2 won’t be the same for different programs](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2709/5472). Not all build versions get a beta number, too. 2. Edit “what can be done” with a description of what you want to do. This is a statement and not a practical question that someone can answer without guessing what you want help with.

Comment: Have you check actual Login Items, as opposed to Launch Agents/Daemons? It used to be in System Prefs, but that's gone iPhone.